# Understanding functional dependencies with pairs

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I'm struggling to wrap my head around how these are supposed to work.

So I have a table of values:

```
╔════╦════╦════╦════╗
║ A  ║ B  ║ C  ║ D  ║
╠════╬════╬════╬════╣
║ A1 ║ B1 ║ C1 ║ D3 ║
║ A1 ║ B2 ║ C3 ║ D2 ║
║ A2 ║ B2 ║ C3 ║ D4 ║
║ A3 ║ B3 ║ C5 ║ D4 ║
╚════╩════╩════╩════╝
```

Now, I think I have the single values sorted.

B is not functionally dependant on `A (A->B)` because A1 corresponds to `B1` and `B2` and so on.

But now I'm being asked if `{A, B} -> C` and I'm not sure I understand it.

Right now I'm thinking that since `{A1, B2}` and {A2, B2} both give `C3`, C cannot be functionally dependant on {A, B}.

I don't even know how to read it. Is it like booleans? If `A -> C` and `B -> C` does that mean `{A, B} -> C`?

If the value on the right (eg C3), corresponds to two unique pairs (A1, B1, and A2, B2) does that mean it's functionally dependant or not?

Answer (score 0):

A functional dependency {A, B} → C means: if in the table there are two tuples with the same combination of values of A and B *then* the value of C must be the same (and not necessarily viceversa).

Note that in general a functional dependency is given not on a single set of data, but is property that should be true on *every* instance of a relation: it is an integrity constraints that say when an instance of a relation schema is valid or not.

Here you have a single instance, and the question that you must answer if is in *this* instance the dependency {A, B} → C holds or not. But the only reasonable answer is “this cannot be answered given the data, since there are no two tuples with the same combination of values of A and B, so that we cannot see if the value of C is equal or different in this case”. Of course your answer will be always limited to that specific instance, and will not have a general validity, as should be for a functional dependency.

On the other hand, you are also asking if a functional dependency can be derived from others: this is possible according to certain rules (that are not applicable in this particular case). To see an example of those rules, you can look for instance at the page on [Armstrong’s axiom on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms).

Comment: So, because {A1, B2} and {A2, B2} both give C3, C is NOT functionally dependant on AB?

But if there were two listings of {A1, B2} which both gave C3, it would?

Comment: @BrickWall, Not necessarily (for the first question). You can say it *does not* depend only if you have two tuples with the same value of A and B and a different value for C.  If instead you have two tuples with A1, B2 with C3, and no other tuples with with A1,B2 and a value for C different from C3, then you can say that in that table C depends on A,B.